# Site deletes text until first punctuation sign

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should ‘Hi’, ‘thanks,’ taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

I posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342245/placing-a-link-on-screen-in-setup-factory-8, and it seems that site deletes text until first punctuation sign. At first it was

> Hi, guys. I'm using ...

but after save, it became

> guys. I'm using ...

What's wrong?

Comment: Stack Exchange automatically deletes greetings and salutations, but it doesn't always get it all.  Think of your posts on Stack Overflow as mini blog posts.  You wouldn't say "Hi guys" at the beginning of a blog post, would you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: [Some](http://anette-olzon.blogspot.no/2012/11/hi-guys.html) [people](http://anxietyuk.healthunlocked.com/blogs/709540/Hi-Guys-Some-advice-please-xx?ref=home) [do](http://manquilters.ning.com/profiles/blogs/3075168:BlogPost:36458), apparently..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I rest my case.

Comment: "Does anyone know what's wrong?"  It didn't also delete "guys."

Comment: @bill HAYYYY GUYYYZZZZZ

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not a bug. That is the expected behavior. Salutations are automatically removed from posts on Stack Exchange. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/152571).